# Trying to construct a specific function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I am trying to construct a function $f$ with the following property:
$\mathbf{N}$ is the set of natural numbers without 0.

Show that

$\forall \epsilon>0: \forall a,b \in \mathbf{N}: a < b:  \exists f: \mathbf{N} \rightarrow \mathbf{N}:  f(a) < \epsilon \cdot f(b).$

Up until now I came up with $f(x) = r^{x \cdot \epsilon}$ with $r \geq 1$. But I can't prove the property for this yet . Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you elaborate why it would be trivial the way I stated it?

Comment: This would be an even stronger statement. I don't necessarily need it but if you can prove this, this is even far more interesting!

Comment: You can define it as $f(a)=1$, $f(b)=[1/\varepsilon]+1$, $f(c)=1$ whenever $c\notin\{a,b\}$. It seems to be a trivial question, so I downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be an integer greater than $1/\epsilon$ and let $f(x)=M^{x-1}$.

Comment: Any reason for $x-1$ rather than $x$?

Comment: No reason, I just like geometric progressions to start at $1$.